# EAGAIN error for accept on blocking socket

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am using a blocking socket to accept connection. I rarely get this error which makes it hard to debug. The accept returns with EAGAIN error. How can that be for a blocking socket?

Answer (score 2):

If the socket has a receive timeout set (with the `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option), then `accept` will return `EAGAIN` when the timeout expires.

This code will demonstrate it (and also let you investigate the effect of delivering a signal):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define TESTEXIT(s, f) if (s < 0) { perror(f); exit(1); }

void handler(int x)
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    int s;
    int r;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    socklen_t sin_len = sizeof sin;
    struct timeval timeo = { .tv_sec = 5, .tv_usec = 0 };

    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

    s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    TESTEXIT(s, "socket");

    r = listen(s, 10);
    TESTEXIT(r, "listen");

    r = setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeo, sizeof timeo);
    TESTEXIT(r, "setsockopt");

    r = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &sin_len);
    TESTEXIT(r, "accept");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the relevant bit of kernel code can be found in net/ipv4/inet_connection_sock.c, in the function inet_csk_wait_for_connect().
It's not entirely clear to me what can happen there but it looks like the function can return -EAGAIN if the wait is interrupted by anything other than a signal (which does return -EINTR).
I don't know what other causes for wakeups there are besided the receive timeout you mentioned though.

Comment: @caf i have a socket with `recv` timeout and i get `EAGAIN` error every timeout period, should i not use timeout with `accept` or is it safe to just catch the error and ignore it?

Comment: @razzak: Well, the whole point of the timeout is that it causes blocking calls to return when the timeout expires, allowing your program to react and maybe do some other work.  So, either have your program respond to the timeout expiring when `EAGAIN` is returned, or if you don't have anything to do when the timeout expires, don't set a timeout.